# Counting fire occurences per county per year using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, csv, count, grouping

[image]

I wish to loop through this shapefile, and for each `"COUNTY_NM"`, count the number of values corresponding to each `"layer"` value.

I want to output a CSV or equivalent which would be show the number of values per each county per year e.g. "Okanogan County, 2000:1, 2002:16, 2003:4" etc.

Comment: you can use vector analysis > statistics by categories

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the ["Statistics by categories"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#statistics-by-categories) from the Vector analysis toolbox in QGIS.

Select your layer, leave *'Field to calculate statistics on'* empty, select `"COUNTY_NM"` and `"layer"` as your *'Field(s) with catagories'*

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is a layer called 'points' with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to *show the number of values per each county per year*.

```sql
SELECT "COUNTY_NM" || ' | ' || GROUP_CONCAT("layer" || ' : ' || n) AS res
FROM (
    SELECT "COUNTY_NM", "layer", COUNT("layer") AS n
    FROM "points"
    GROUP BY "layer", "COUNTY_NM")
GROUP BY "COUNTY_NM"
ORDER BY "COUNTY_NM", "layer", n
```

The output attribute table will look like

[image: output]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create a virtal layer in the modeler? I cant find a tool / algorithm for it

Comment: I think this can help you: [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#execute-sql) in QGIS Graphical Modeler